# C# sql like statement don't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-like

Hello and good day to all. I have a little question about like statement of sql/c#, I can't figure out why my code doesn't work.

```
if (Combo_List.Text == "What")
{
   listView1.Items.Clear();
   myds.Clear();
   mydaEvents.SelectCommand = myconn.CreateCommand();
   mydaEvents.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from Eventstbl where What like '@what%'";
   mydaEvents.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   mydaEvents.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@what", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 2000, "What").Value = text_Search.Text;
   mydaEvents.Fill(myds, "Eventstbl");

   foreach (DataRow item in myds.Tables["Eventstbl"].Rows)
   {
       ListViewItem items = new ListViewItem(item["EventsID"].ToString());
       items.SubItems.Add(item["What"].ToString());
       listView1.Items.Add(items);
   }
}
```

The @what% won't work but when I put 'a%' all items that begin in letter a shows in my listview1. I don't know how to fix this issue. help me please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: try "select ... where what like @what + '%'"

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, per se.  And I don't see a question.  I also do not see an explanation of what the issue is.

Comment: i forgot to say, when im using '@what%' and i entered character or number nothing show in my listview but when i use 'a%' all data that starts from letter a shows from my listview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
mydaEvents.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select * from Eventstbl where What like @what + '%'";
```

Text inside quotes will be treated as...text - you want your parameter to be interpreted as its string *value*, so you have to move it out.

Comment: thank you for the help and a small explanation. this is the first time i used like statement. thank you for helping me it works now :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing the problem is that `'@what%'` is being treated as a literal rather than getting replaced with the value of your parameter.

Try doing `@what + '%'` instead.